# PHP output_buffering works only with error_reporting(E_ALL) issue

Tags: php, output-buffering, ob-start

I have a PHP script, this is a part of:

```
if($signature == $params_signature) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    ob_start();
    echo 'OK'; // send the OK response
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Encoding: none");
    header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    echo 'test';
    // some further procesiing
    exit;
}
```

So the issue is: ob_start() working properly only in there is error_reporting settings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

In this case output is "OK", but if I remove error_reporting part output is "OKtest".

The problem is, that I can not leave error reporting on production site, and I can not figure out the reason why this is happenning.

Maybe some more information is needded?!

UPDATE: Expected behavior: sctipt sends responce with status 200 and body - "OK", closes connection, and proceedes doing some internal stuff.

Comment: Have you already checked your error logs when `error_reporting` is enabled?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have logs access on remote server

Comment: I have no idea why you'd expect the connection to close and `test` not to be output. Nothing in your code says "close connection and continue doing other stuff".

Comment: OK, may be I am wrong about connection closing, but still it sends only "OK" in body, and finishes execution properly, but the only thing I confused with is that stops working on remote server without error_reporting, and I need a hint to find out why and fix it.
Can you be more precise, and describe what happens if not connection closing?
Thanks!

Comment: Well nothing happens really. You're repeatedly telling it to flush content to the client, but that doesn't close any connections. There's likely some minor difference in buffer behaviours on your production server, which is why the output may or may not show up; but your code is far from doing what you want it to to begin with, so that's the wrong point to concentrate on.

Comment: I spent little time investigating: 
    _ob_end_flush();_
    _ob_flush();_
    _flush();_
so, these functions, in exactly this order, make things work,
_ob_end_flush()_ stopts buffering and _flush()_ in conjuction with _ob_flush()_ pushes all output in request body, and prevents script from further output (I don't know exactly how). So I can say, that _flush()_ makes all work here, and _header('Connection: close')_ makes no sense at all. 
That is all I found out with my poor PHP knowleges.
Any additions from advansed PHPers?

Comment: And also it ingtores _sleep(10)_ function (without _flush()_ in takes 10 more secs execution time in browser profile)

Answer (score 0):

The below code works without `error_reporting`:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    echo 'OK'; // send the OK response
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Encoding: none");
    header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());

    echo 'test';
    // some further procesiing

    exit;
?>
```

I have removed this before your last echo,

```
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Comment: I am afraid in is not working as expected. I think the issue might be connected to server enviroment, becaue I have no problems on my local machine. But still thanks!